# UNION and MIN/MAX with Grouping and Odd Date Request

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, ssms-2016

This is a new version of my question, since it seems to be confusing.  Sorry. I figured it out.  See the code if you're interested.  Notes to solve are in there.  Thanks for your help!

I got it to work this far, but the OriginaionL (L is for Little and B is for Big) is not correct.  It's taking the correct date but not Origination.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  LoadTagID                 INT,
  EnteredDateTime           datetime,
  JobNumber                 VARCHAR(50),
  Origination               VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1, '2015-02-09 00:00:00.00',   11111,   'Here')
,(2, '2015-02-09 00:00:00.00',    22222,   'There')
,(3, '2016-03-09 00:00:00.00',    11111,   'Outside')
,(4, '2016-08-09 00:00:00.00',    12578,   'Anywhere')
,(252, '2017-06-29 00:00:00.00',   12345,   'Here')
,(253, '2017-08-01 00:00:00.00',    99999,   'There')
,(254, '2017-08-04 00:00:00.00',    12345,   'Outside')
,(255, '2017-08-09 00:00:00.00',    12345,   'Anywhere')
,(256, '2017-08-10 00:00:00.00',    99999,   'Anywhere')
,(257, '2017-08-10 00:00:00.00',    123456,   'Anywhere')
,(258, '2017-08-11 00:00:00.00',    123456,   'Over Yonder')
,(259, '2017-08-13 00:00:00.00',    99999,   'Under The Bridge')

--Select * From MyTable

CREATE TABLE #LTTB1         --MAX
( 
    LoadTagID varchar(50), 
    JobNumber varchar(50), 
    EnteredDateTime varchar(50), 
    Origination varchar(50)
)
CREATE TABLE #LTTB2         --MIN
(
    LoadTagID varchar(50), 
    JobNumber varchar(50), 
    EnteredDateTime varchar(50),         
    Origination varchar(50) 
)
CREATE TABLE #LTTB3
(
    LoadTagIDL varchar(50), 
    JobNumberL varchar(50), 
    EnteredDateTimeL 
    varchar(50), 
    OriginationL varchar(50)
    , LoadTagID varchar(50), 
    JobNumber varchar(50), 
    EnteredDateTime varchar(50), 
    Origination varchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO #LTTB1
SELECT 
    MAX(LoadTagID) AS LoadTagID, 
    JobNumber,
    MAX(EnteredDateTime) AS EnteredDateTime, 
    MAX(Origination) AS Origination
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT (Date, EnteredDateTime) >= CONVERT (Date, GETDATE()-10) --Gets the last 10 days.  
GROUP BY JobNumber ORDER BY JobNumber

INSERT INTO #LTTB2
SELECT  MIN(LoadTagID) AS LoadTagIDL, 
    JobNumber AS JobNumberL,
    MIN(EnteredDateTime) AS EnteredDateTimeL, 
    MAX(Origination) AS OriginationL  --MAX! This needed to be max!! Why?
FROM MyTable
Where CONVERT (Date, EnteredDateTime) >= CONVERT (Date, GETDATE()-60) --Goes further back in case one is a long. 
GROUP BY JobNumber ORDER BY JobNumber

INSERT INTO #LTTB3
SELECT    L.LoadTagID AS LoadTagIDL 
    , L.JobNumber  AS JobNumberL
    , L.EnteredDateTime AS EnteredDateTimeL
    , L.Origination AS OriginationL  
    , B.LoadTagID, B.JobNumber, B.EnteredDateTime, B.Origination 
FROM #LTTB1 B  --MAX
INNER JOIN #LTTB2 L ON B.JobNumber = L.JobNumber

Select * From #LTTB3
```

So for JobNumber 12345 6/29 is correct, but it should be "Here" and not "Anywhere:

For 99999 everything is correct but for 8/1 it should be "There" and not Anywhere.  That seems to be the middle value in the set. I'm so confused.

Does anyone know why it's grabbing that value?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE LoadTagID=(SELECT MIN(LoadTagID) 
                 FROM mytable) 
OR LoadTagID=(SELECT MAX(LoadTagID) 
              FROM mytable);
```

query according to the output you want

Comment: Thank you.  This would work but it only selects the min and max and returns 2 rows.  I need it grouped by the job number.  So it should return 2 records for each job, which could be hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  LoadTagID     INT,
  Date          Date,
  Job           INT,
  Origination   VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES(
       252, '6/29/17',   12345,   'Here')
     ,(253, '8/1/17',    99999,   'There')
     ,(254, '8/4/17',    12345,   'Outside')
     ,(255, '8/8/17',    12345,   'Anywhere')

--SELECT * FROM MyTable

SELECT * INTO #Table1 
FROM MyTable
WHERE LoadTagID IN (SELECT MIN(LoadTagID) 
                    FROM MyTable)

SELECT * INTO #Table2 
FROM MyTable
WHERE LoadTagID IN (SELECT MAX(LoadTagID) 
                    FROM MyTable)

SELECT * INTO #T3
FROM ( SELECT * FROM #Table1 T1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM #Table2 T2
     ) A

SELECT  #T3.Date,
        #T3.Job,
        #T3.LoadTagID,
        #T3.Origination
FROM #T3
LEFT JOIN #Table1 T1
ON T1.Job=#T3.Job
WHERE T1.Job IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is close but it is not grouped by job and it is missing the date.  Well it's not missing the date but I can't group by the job and have it return the date.  This is what I have so far.  Thank you
    Select Max(LoadTagID) as Max, Jobnumber
    INTO #Table1 
    From MyTable
    Where Convert (Date, EnteredDateTime) >= Convert (Date, 
    GETDATE()-7)
    Group By JobNumber
    Order By JobNumber

   Select Min(LoadTagID) as Min, Jobnumber
    INTO #Table2 
    From MyTable
    Group By JobNumber

Comment: Well I have it working better and have updated my original question so everyone can understand.  It's working but I'm missing the two main columns that they want to see.  So I have to figure out how to do that with a group by.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added more data to the sample set.  It's not returning the right values yet.  It's a lot closer though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please give some details about the output of above insert data? Please send me the output details

Comment: I re-wrote my initial question with a data set that includes the correct output. It is Select * From #LTTB3  Hope that helps.

Comment: Added one more solution for minimum job origination.

Comment: Thank you.  This would work but it is only returning one record.  The Select Min only returns one record. It should be returning about 100.  It has to select the min that is grouped by the job.  Hopefully I'm making sense.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #LTTB1
SELECT 
    MAX(LoadTagID) AS LoadTagID, 
    JobNumber,
    MAX(EnteredDateTime) AS EnteredDateTime, 
    MAX(Origination) AS Origination
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT (Date, EnteredDateTime) >= CONVERT (Date, GETDATE()-10) --Gets the last 10 days.  
GROUP BY JobNumber ORDER BY JobNumber

INSERT INTO #LTTB2
select LoadTagID
,JobNumber
,EnteredDateTime
,Origination from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by jobnumber order by EnteredDateTime) l
from MyTable
Where CONVERT (Date, EnteredDateTime) >= CONVERT (Date, GETDATE()-60) 
)lk
where lk.l=1

INSERT INTO #LTTB3
SELECT    L.LoadTagID AS LoadTagIDL 
    , L.JobNumber  AS JobNumberL
    , L.EnteredDateTime AS EnteredDateTimeL
    , L.Origination AS OriginationL  
    , B.LoadTagID, B.JobNumber, B.EnteredDateTime, B.Origination 
FROM #LTTB1 B  --MAX
INNER JOIN #LTTB2 L ON B.JobNumber = L.JobNumber


Select * From MyTable
Select * From #LTTB3

--I hope, your prob has been solved now..
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I had it working but it is still not right.  I think doing a Min or Max on the Origination is part of the problem.  This is closer, but  table one is grabbing the wrong Origination.  It is the correct date.  Any ideas? Thank you.